# JDBC PreparedStatement setLong

Tags: java

I have a column in my table that is a customer id, and is pretty big. I have the below prepared statement

```
String SQL = "SELECT CUSTOMER_INFO FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?";
```

Basically I want the result of the below query - `SELECT CUSTOMER_INFO FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 2014070815`

How do I achieve this using preparedStatement?If I do this -

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
ps.setString(1, "2014070815");
```

Clearly it won't work since it is not a string. I also tried setLong, but setLong fails for a few customer ids with the error `The literal 0802030158L of type long is out of range`. Please please give me your inputs here.

Comment: What is the datatype of `customer_id` in DB?

Comment: Then why don't you pass a string in from the code? Convert your input to string first and then use `setString`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: I already tried ps.setString(1, "2014070815");

Comment: `char` datatype means you are storing as text data, not as numeric data. So how about using `setString` to pass in the value as a string, which is what it gets stored as in DB? What error are you getting when you try to use `setString`?

Comment: From the failed example I would assume that you sometimes will need leading `0`s which you will only get across by `String`

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, but it is returning an empty resultset. When I debug, the statement resolves to SELECT CUSTOMER_INFO FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 2014070815, while it should be SELECT CUSTOMER_INFO FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '2014070815'

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the CUSTOMER_ID column is a CHAR and not a VARCHAR?

Comment: I am not sure. The table is not created by my team. We only read the data in this table, and have no control over it.

Comment: What happens when you use a Statement object instead of a PreparedStatement and pass raw SQL, eg: statement.executeQuery("SELECT CUSTOMER_INFO FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '2014070815'"). Does this return a result?

Comment: It works with Statement.

Comment: I'd say there is a problem with the CHAR column itself. String comparisons don't seem to work too well on fixed char columns because databases tend to add padding to the data, and your string value doesn't exactly match the padded data. I guess you can either use the raw SQL and Statement approach, or you can change the the database column to a VARCHAR. The latter would certainly be the better approach.